# Как залить субмодули в удаленный репозиторий?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodule

Создал репозиторий на bitbucket, залил проект, однако в проекте имелось пару модулей, которые имели внутри себя репозитории Git. 
В итоге папки этих модулей не открываются на bitbucket.

Я удалил из этих папок Git репозитории в локальном проекте, но они не идут в add и не комитятся.

`.gitignore` нету.

Когда делаю `pull` с bitbucket то папки которые были со своими Git пустые.

**Как можно затереть эти папки и файлы на сервере своими локальными копиями?**

---

Что если я сделаю checkout и укажу удаленную ветку, а потом сделаю git rm для этих папок, сделаю commit.
Потом вернусь в master и накачу pull, а потом сделаю add и push, может получится?

Похоже, что нет. Файлы остаются те же.
Вопрос остается, выделенный жирным.

Comment: тебе нужен `git submodule` либо `git subtree`

Comment: я прочитал описание по ссылке
http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8

Но это не решает мою проблему. 

root@:/srv/asb.ru# git submodule init
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'modules/minion'
root@:/srv/asb.ru# git submodule update
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'modules/minion'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заработало!!!

Сначала я вернул файлы Git в папки git init.

Потом сделал 
`git rm --cached 'modules/minion'`

и для второй папки

а потом
`git submodule add ./modules/minion modules/minion`

и для второй папки так же

После этого они добавились через commit и стали отображаться на bitbucket

Через git subtree можно будет избавиться от модулей, сделать их каталогами, если надо.

Comment: На другом сервере сделался git pull
Теперь там нужно сделать 

git submodule init

и обновлять модули

git submodule update